# How to open a github repository in VisualStudio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I installed a new version of VS 17.6.1 and trying to open a forked repository from my github. I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-open-project-from-repo?view=vs-2022) and tried git -> clone repository. But that gives me an error "repository checked out but no solution found". Then I cloned the repo to my local machine and tried file -> open to open it as a project. But it doesn't let me open the folder but just a single file. How do I open a repo in VS?

Comment: It's sounds like your source code is missing a `.sln` or `.prj` file. I suggest you take look in the local folder that you have cloned to and find the `.prj` or `.sln` file. If you can't find one then these files simply can't be opened in visual studio. What type of source code is it? web? data? Can you find the `.prj` or `.sln` file in the actual online github repo?

Comment: right, I don't have .prj or .sln files in my repo. The repo is for creating a github page based on a template. I thought I could open it in VS, edit it, and deploy it. I forked al-folio template.

Comment: I suggest you use VS Code instead. It'll happily open any folder and has add ins to help editing various projec types